# Pesquisa de texto no realtime database (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, realtime-database

Boa noite estou precisando customizar uma pesquisa para recuperar dados do realtime database.

Atualmente utilizo o seguinte código para consultar um item do meu banco de dados:

```
query = databaseReference.child("itens").orderByChild("nomeItem").startAt(textoDeEntrada).endAt(textoDeEntrada+"\uf8ff");
```

Com este código, se eu tiver um item (nomeItem) com o seguinte conteúdo "bola de futebol de salão" no meu banco e pesquisar por "bola" eu encontro a resposta, porém, se eu pesquisar por "futebol" nada é retornado.

O que posso utilizar para que o item seja retornado se eu pesquisar por qualquer uma das palavras contidas no conteúdo do item? Ou seja, independentemente se eu digitar "bola", "futebol", "de" ou "salão" eu encontre a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do link, não é possível fazer isso diretamente no Firebase.

Você pode, em vez disso, carregar todos os dados e filtrá-los no seu código.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database